# Web link in html duplicating itself?

Tags: html, odoo, odoo-website

Newb at html and web... anything beyond usage. I'm not even sure this is the correct forum for this question.

I placed a link in the html for a container (image and text) that I had inserted into the footer of our page.

I inserted the code for the link to surround the image and text sections of that part of the container.

```
<div class="blah blah"
   <a href="etc.etc">
      <img
```

Continue on until after the last line of text

```
    </a>
</div>
```

It was nice, clean, and the link encompassed the image and both lines of text.

I check an hour later, and every line of text and the image now have the link info repeated individually, and strangely duplicated between the lines of text for no apparent reason.

Running the site with odoo, based on bootstrap if I remember correctly.

Why is it duplicating the link information repeatedly?

It works fine, it's just ugly when going in to edit the code, and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong to cause it to happen.

Edit:
here is the current code, after apparent self duplication:

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <a href="http://edited/" target="_blank" title="edited&#10;http://edited/">
        <img class="fa-suitcase img-rounded" src="/website/image/ir.attachment/1143_1cc91ea/datas" style=""/>
    </a>
    <h3 class="mt8 mb0">
        <a href="http://edited/" target="_blank" title="edited&#10;http://edited/">
            <span style="color:#FFFFFF;">edited</span>
        </a>
    </h3>
    <a href="http://edited/" target="_blank" title="edited&#10;http://edited/"></a>
    <div class="text-muted">
        <a href="http://edited/" target="_blank" title="edited&#10;http://edited/">
            <span style="color:#D3D3D3;">edited</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="http://edited/" target="_blank" title="edited&#10;http://edited/"></a>
</div>
```

When it was originally entered, it was this:

```
<a href="http://edited/" target="_blank" title="edited&#10;http://edited/">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <img class="fa-suitcase img-rounded" src="/website/image/ir.attachment/1143_1cc91ea/datas" style=""/>
    <h3 class="mt8 mb0">
      <span style="color:#FFFFFF;">edited</span>
    </h3>
    <div class="text-muted">
      <span style="color:#D3D3D3;">edited</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `>` in the opening `div`.  Is that just a typo here?  Can you post the full html?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing this up on my phone while taking a break. That was me simply trying to shorthand it.

Comment: Dropped in the code for both before and after, and tested the clean version on the site. It works, but returns to the duplicated version after a time.

Comment: Looks like your browser/dev system doesn't like a div inside an `<a>` tag.  Try changing all your divs to inline elements (with `display:block`) and see if that helps.

Comment: Hmm... I'll look up how to do that and give it a shot. Like I said, I'm a newb. I'm teaching myself as I go, so it's all new to me, except for the base concepts.

Comment: For a simple test, just replace `div` with `p`.